# How to remove duplicates from a filter function

Tags: excel, filter, duplicates

[image]

Right now I have the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",0,FILTER(A3:A9,$E$3=$B$3:B$9))
```

What I want is for each different element from the filter to be returned only once. Essentially, I don't want "hello" to be returned twice and instead the output should just be:

`"hello, pear, Apple, lemon"`.

I feel like this should be a really simple thing but I am very bad at Excel so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Where would I put the unique?

Comment: Outside the `FILTER`?

Comment: Ok perfect that worked! Follow up, do you know if there's a way to ignore any results that may have a certain character (like an underscore)?

Comment: You can add a condition to your filter, e.g. using `NOT`, `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH`.

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(", ",0,UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A10,$E$3=$B$3:B$10*NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_",$B$3:$B$10))))))

Comment: Why is that not working?

Comment: I added a test case of _hello in column a and france in column b

Comment: You're missing some brackets: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",0,UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A10,($E$3=$B$3:B$10)*(ISERROR(SEARCH("_",$B$3:$B$10))))))`